# Why my laravel website reloading after completion of timeout time of loader

Tags: php, jquery, refresh, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I am working on laravel project along with jquery for reference you can visit on "http://etailor.fudugosolutions.in/designshirts" site. 
While I click on options of fabric tab, what actually happening is after completion of time of loader is 3000ms my web page is get refreshing although I haven't use location.reload function in Js.
I would like to tell you that instead of refreshing the page, I am replacing the complete HTML elements of page. 
Kindly please help me for solving this issue.

This is my Js code where I am receiving data from Controller.

```
function getfab(id,jArray,otab){    
var arr=jArray;
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:'/designshirts',
   data:{fabid : id, carr : arr, typ : 'fabric', t : otab},
   beforeSend: function() {
      $(".et-small-loader").show();
   },
   headers: {
'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
   success:function(data){         
        $('body').html(data);
        setTimeout($(".et-small-loader").fadeOut(),1000);
   }
});
}
```

Here from .html(data) I am replacing my html in Blade.

Comment: Can you provide the code you've written, rather than just a link to your website? Is there an AJAX call or something? We need to see this code :)

Comment: Yes their is an Ajax call. but scenario is once the response is loaded in controller, I am directly calling it on my bled.php, It is not possible to paste full code here  because it is very lengthy. @samiles

Comment: Paste just the necessary

Comment: Please check my updated code above @manix